# How can i use "GTR" and "LSS" in one line

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I want to know how to use "greater than" and "less than" in one line
I want to make a range of numbers like from 20-30 (20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30.)

```
    If %number% GTR 20 LSS 30 echo "this is inside 20-30"
```

if i do this then i get an error:
LSS is not recognized as an internal or external command.
Please help im making a truck game and i need this.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use 2 IF statements

```
if %number% geq 20 if %number% leq 30 echo %number% is between 20-30 inclusive
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a simple arithmetic trick to do this test:

```
set /A "range=0,b=(20-number)*(number-30),range=(b-1)/b" 2>nul
if %range% equ 0 echo this is inside 20-30
```

This method allows you to test if a number is inside anyone of *several ranges* just extending the arithmetic expression and using *one* `if` command; you must note that this method also allows you to correctly use an `else` part in the simplest way. Further details at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3493).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a logical and operator in DOS batch files. To accomplish what you want you will need to nest them as such:

```
if %number% gtr 20 (if %number% lss 30 ( echo "this is inside 20-30"))
```